# Create pattern list dynamically from file for running in grep -f

Tags: bash, grep, xargs

Lets say I have this input

```
11
12
31
40
42
90
```

I need to get all number lines from the file and add the `|` character after each that can be used as a pattern list to run with `grep -f`.

I was thinking of using `xargs` but I have no idea how to use `|` as a separator or put the args in the middle of a string

```
grep -P "(11|12|31|40|42|90)\|" o.txt
```

Comment: You can just use that file with `-f`?

Comment: @daniu almost. I need to add `\|` to the end of each line and maybe something at the start. I completely forgot grep can use `-f`

Comment: No unless I misunderstand it. I need any numbers in the file and the character `|` after it. I do not want the first number `|` second number `|` etc. It also looks like I might want a suffix and I'm a little unsure how to add it without a space but maybe I'll use a python script since I know how to debug it

Comment: Give an example input which shows what is the expected outcome.  I honestly don't see what you want to achieve. Also explain in what respect the `grep` statement you have suggested, does not work correctly.

Comment: BTW, in your pattern, I don't see why you need `-P`. Wouldn't `-E` be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
grep -E -f <(sed -E '/^[0-9]+$/!d;s/.*/&\\|/' numbers.txt) file.txt
```

First, get all lines that only contain digit from the `numbers.txt`, append to each found line a `\|`, and then use this as a pattern file with `-f` option to `grep`. The `file.txt` is a file where you are looking for matches.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/hyFLai):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
text='Some 11 number and 11| that we need
Redundant line'
s="11
12
31
40
42
90"
grep -E -f <(sed -E '/^[0-9]+$/!d;s/.*/&\\|/' <<< "$s") <<< "$text"
# => Some 11 number and 11| that we need
grep -oE -f <(sed -E '/^[0-9]+$/!d;s/.*/&\\|/' <<< "$s") <<< "$text"
# => 11|
```

Comment: I'll probably accept in the morning. To tired to test

Comment: @EricStotch :) It is 9:44 AM in Warsaw, Poland, now.